# Alternative of setting spring bean properties

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My application uses XML base spring configuration and I'd like to move this config to @Configuration class since Spring 3.0 onward support these annotations.

For example Here is my bean in XML,

```
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.mycom.AnnotatedEntity</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I tried following,

```
@Configuration
public class Config{

    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    private Driver driverClassName;

    @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public DBDao dao(){
        return new DaoImpl(sessionFactory()); 
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        Class<?>[] annotatedClasses = null;
        annotatedClasses.getClass();
        localSessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        localSessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(annotatedClasses);
        return (SessionFactory) localSessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource(){
        SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriver(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

The question is how do I set "annotatedClasses" and "hibernateProperties" properties in configuration class?

Comment: If you're migrating configurations, see if it's possible to go with Spring Boot. All of this can be handled for you automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotated classes takes var args. So like this:

```
localSessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(SomeEntity.class, AnotherEntity.class);
```

To set hibernate properties:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect");
properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);

sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(properties);
```

Sidenote: Don't cast `LocalSessionFactoryBean` to `SessionFactory`. Simply return:

```
localSessionFactory.getObject();
```

Comment: Hi Branislav, many thanks for the reply, I have transactionManager in my XML <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

 <bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
 </bean> what would be equivalent in configuration class? "transactionManager" @Bean and setting a props are straight but what about <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

Comment: @Rakesh Use `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation over your configuration class. :) More details [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html)

Comment: Hi Branislav, after adding     @EnableTransactionManagement, getting null pointer Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.transactionAdvisor(ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.java:46)
 at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f793f1c8.CGLIB$transactionAdvisor$0(<generated>)
 at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f793f1c8$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$46c91349.invo